# How to Convert JavaScript keyboard-transformation function into PHP Code?

Tags: javascript, php, function, converters

Can anyone help me convert this JavaScript code into PHP?  I already tried to convert it to PHP but it only returns error.

```
function TransformedText () { 
  this.horizontalFlipValue = [];
}

// Horizontal Flip Function this is  method prototype
TransformedText.prototype.horizontalFlip = function (outputtedText) {
  this.horizontalFlipValue = []; 
  for (var i = 0; i < outputtedText.length; i ++)
  {
    //Find which array character is in
    if ($.inArray(outputtedText[i], row1) != -1) {  
      //Find place value of character in array
      charactersPlaceInArray = row1.indexOf(outputtedText[i], row1);
      this.horizontalFlipValue.push(row1[(row1.length - 1) - charactersPlaceInArray]);
    }
  }
  outputtedText = this.horizontalFlipValue;
}
```

This is what i have so far:

```
    public function __construct () {
        $this->horizontalFlipValue = [];
    }

    public function flipHorizontal($outputtedText) { 
        $this->horizontalFlipValue = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->outputtedText); $i++) {
            if(in_array($outputtedText[$i], $row1) != -1) {
                $charactersPlaceInArray = $row1.strpos(count($outputtedText[i]),$row1);
                $this->horizontalFlipValue.push($row1[(count($row1)-1)-$charactersPlaceInArray]);
            }
        }
    $outputtedText = $this->horizontalFlipValue;
    }   
}
```

Comment: What error are you seeing returned?

Comment: it's a bit abstract, can we have examples of incoming and outgoing data for this function?

Comment: @MisterJojo These transforms apply to a 4 row x 10 column section of keys on a standard qwerty keyboard. The 4 rows start with 1, q, a, z and extend to 0, p, ;, /, respectively. And the function will flip all rows of the keyboard horizontally (e.g., the 1 will swap with the 0, the 2 with the 9, etc.).

Comment: @BDD I tried to change the JavaScript's `inArray, indexOf and push` functions into a PHP function.

Answer (score 0):

> These transforms apply to a 4 row x 10 column section of keys on a standard qwerty keyboard. The 4 rows start with 1, q, a, z and extend to 0, p, ;, /, respectively. And the function will flip all rows of the keyboard horizontally (e.g., the 1 will swap with the 0, the 2 with the 9, etc.).

I can easy answering that :

```js
const doInverseString =s=>[...s].reverse().join('')

console.log ( doInverseString( '1234567890') )  // 0987654321
console.log ( doInverseString( 'qwertyuiop') )  // poiuytrewq
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but it is not just reversed. For example when I try to enter only a single "q" character, it will returns "p".

Answer (score 0):

thank you for trying to help, but I've resolved the error. An error occurred while trying to change "JavaScript's inArray, indexOf and push functions" to the similar function in PHP. jQuery's `inArray` is the same as the `in_array` function in PHP. JavaScript's `indexOf` similar to PHP's `array_search` and `push` similar to `array_push` in PHP.

```
function TransformedText($outputtedText) {
    $cOutputText = count($outputtedText);
    $charactersPlaceInArray;
    $horizontalFlipValue = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $cOutputText; $i++){
        if(in_array($outputtedText[$i], $row1)){
            $charactersPlaceInArray = array_search($outputtedText[$i], $row1);
            array_push($horizontalFlipValue, $row1[($cRow1 -1 ) - $charactersPlaceInArray]);
        }
$outputtedText = $horizontalFlipValue;
}
```